# Set custom image from bottom to top inside bars of bar graph (using highcharts)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, highcharts, char

So I have added custom image inside bars of bar graph (chart library highcharts). But the images are filled from top to bottom so the image at the bottom is cut but the x-axis (image attached below).

[bar graph with custom image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg6rO.png)

Code I have written till now

```
var redrawEnabled = true,
        ctr = 0;
        Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                events: {
                    load: function(){
                        if(this.options.chart.type == 'column'){
                            this.xAxis[0].update({
                            reversed: false
                        });
                        }
                    },
                render: function() {
                    if (redrawEnabled) {
                        redrawEnabled = false;
                        var chart = this,
                            renderer = chart.renderer;
                            
                            chart.series[0].points.forEach(function(p) {
                            
                            var widthRatio = p.shapeArgs.width / p.shapeArgs.height
                            id = 'pattern-' + p.index + '-' + ctr;

                            var pattern = renderer.createElement('pattern').add(renderer.defs).attr({
                            width: 1,
                            height: widthRatio,
                            id: id,
                            patternContentUnits: 'objectBoundingBox'
                            });
                            renderer.image('coin6.png', 0, 0, 1, widthRatio).attr({}).add(pattern);

                            p.update({
                            color: 'url(#' + id + ')'
                            }, false);
                        });

                        ctr++;
                        chart.redraw();
                        redrawEnabled = true;
                    }
                }
            },

            },
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            legend:{ enabled:false },
            
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                style: {
                        color: 'red',
                        fontSize:'10px'
                    }
                },
                categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
                ],
                crosshair: false,
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                tickLength: 0,
                visible: false,
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                },
                
            },
            series: [{
                pointWidth: 30,
                data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5,]
            }]
            });
```

1st :- So I want start the image from the bottom so that it looks similar at bottom. so I want the image pattern flow from bottom to top.
2nd :- Can I apply padding and margin to the image pattern so that I can stack the coin images properly

I want to achieve the stack of coin as image attached.
[final result I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qbx4.png)

Comment: Please reproduce your case on some online editor that I could work on. Here is my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/st17869e/ - it seems that this image link is needed

Comment: Hii @SebastianWędzel , I have created the working jsfiddle : link:- https://jsfiddle.net/lalitcse/4mz8pwab/5/ and image link :- https://i.ibb.co/BZ9phG2/coin6.png . thanks

Comment: @SebastianWędzel and I want add different coin image for future month ( in future months predicted data will come) as show in this image :- ( https://i.ibb.co/R2v6S5b/one.png ). Future date coin image link ( https://i.ibb.co/WnfycgC/preddict-coin.png ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xAxis.offset` feature to increase this space.

```
   xAxis: {
     labels: {
       style: {
         color: 'red',
         fontSize: '10px'
       }
     },
         offset: 50,
     categories: [
       'Jan',
       'Feb',
       'Mar',
       'Apr',
       'May',
       'Jun',
       'Jul',
       'Aug',
       'Sep',
       'Oct',
       'Nov',
       'Dec'
     ],
     crosshair: false,
   },
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0wqnbtdz/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.offset

Comment: But I want to reduce the space between the coin images inside the bars so that they are stacked properly on upon one. like this image ( https://i.ibb.co/R2v6S5b/one.png )

Comment: I want to achieve bar graph exactly like this image (  https://i.ibb.co/R2v6S5b/one.png ) . I am not able to create exact bar graph like this. Can you just tell me how to achieve this or you know any library through which I can create bar graph exactly like this ( https://i.ibb.co/R2v6S5b/one.png ). Thanks

Comment: You will need to provide this coin image as an SVG element. Notice that now this image has a white background. https://i.ibb.co/BZ9phG2/coin6.png

Comment: I have added svg coin image ( working jsfiddle link :- https://jsfiddle.net/lalitcse/4mz8pwab/7/ ) results are same. can we apply negative margin between to svg coin images . My client wants graph exactly like this ( https://i.ibb.co/R2v6S5b/one.png). thanks

Comment: I am afraid that it is impossible to achieve with this image. Notice that it is a rectangle and each rectangle is rendered above the next one.